# How can I make group headers selectable in a ListBox using custom GroupItem implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, styles

I'm trying to figure out how I can modify the ListBox control so that group headers are also selectable.

[image: Enter]

My idea is that I could add an "IsSelected" property to the GroupItem (or maybe Expander?) class and then handle the logic in a custom version of the ListBox control.

I've tried looking at the ItemsControl, ListBox & GroupItem class on MSDN, but I've not been able to spot how the GroupItem is connected to the aforementioned controls.

Does anybody know how I could accomplish this?

I know StackOverflow is a Q&A site, but if anyone want's to suggest a better method, feel free!

NOTE: The suggestion should be MVVM compatible.

EDIT: I also thought of using a TreeView, but then I can't filter the items using a CollectionViewSource.

Comment: Why would you want to select Group headers? These are headers, they are made to not be selectable, maybe you should just go with custom ItemTemplate?

Comment: I'm creating a port manager, and one should be able to add/edit groups & ports. The idea is that when an item is selected, a region on the right is populated with an "editor" view. This should support an editor view for both groups and ports.
I initially decided to use the ListBox because it supported groups/headers, but I'd obviously not thought it all through.. If I did it via an item template, wouldn't the group be repeated for each item?

Comment: To be true, i don't know what do you mean, could you draw some example?

Comment: Hopefully this clears it up for you: https://i.imgur.com/j5CwqM3.jpg